# Output of NuGet to stream results in wrapping at 60 characters

Tags: c#, nuget

The following code spins up a NuGet process and lists out packages matching the input argument.

```
using(var p = new Process())
{
    var nugetPackageToLookFor = "635309301071616794UploadAndDownLoadPackageWith";
    var nugetPath = @"C:\NuGet.exe";

    p.StartInfo.FileName = nugetPath;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"list {0}", nugetPackageToLookFor);
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream))
    {
        sr.ReadLine().Dump();
    }
}
```

Note: The package name I used above is just one of the first results returned (with a character length > 60) from a full list.

This outputs the first 60 characters of the package name, adds a CRLF and continues on the next line.

The output is:

> 635309301071616794UploadAndDownLoadPackageWithMinClientVers
>   ion 1.0.0

Whereas I'm expecting:

> 635309301071616794UploadAndDownLoadPackageWithMinClientVersion 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this is a bug in an older version of NuGet.

https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3673